# GR Tetrads & ZAMO example

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I am self-learning GR.

**Intro**: Tetrads are a way of representing general relativity in a coordinate-independent fashion.

I am having trouble understanding tetrad notations. Basically, I know that I can transform e.g. 4-velocities between tetrad frames by: $e^m_{\ \mu} x^\mu=x^m$.

**Problem**: Most sources, however, give tetrads in some funny form by simply introducing vectors (example: [equation 12 for Zero Angular Momentum Observer tetrad](http://events.asiaa.sinica.edu.tw/school/20070129/talk/960129cai.pdf)):

e.g. $\gamma^{(t)}=|g_{tt}-\omega^2 g_{\phi phi}|^{1/2} dt$

Which is somehow related to the tetrad *basis vectors*.

**Question**: **I)** Is there any simple way to understand tetrad basis vectors, **II)** how can I relate the tetrad basis to vierbeins $e^m_{\ \mu}$ and **III)** are there any inherent symmetries in vierbeins e.g. $e^m_{\ \mu}$?

**Note**: I have mainly read physics books which did not deal with differential geometry

Comment: I guess my biggest confusion comes from the fact that $e^m_{\ \ \mu}$ is not the same as $e_{\mu}^{\ \ m}$?

Comment: One's the "inverse" of the other (if we pretend they're both square matrices), recall ${e^{\mu}}_{m}{e^{\nu}}_{n}g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{mn}$, then ${e^{\mu}}_{m}{e^{m}}_{\nu}=\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tetrad and vielbein are exactly the same thing. The tetrad is just a set of four vectors $e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3$ which is *orthonormal* at each point:
$$g(e_i,e_j)=\eta_{ij}=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$$
Here $g$ is the metric tensor of spacetime. The vectors $e_i$ have components with respect to some coordinates $x^\mu$, we denote these coordinate components by $e_i{}^\mu$. Here $i$ denotes which one of the four vectors we are talking about and $\mu$ which coordinate component. Since $\mu$ and $i$ go over $4$ values, this is actually a matrix, and can be shown to be invertible. We denote its matrix inverse by $e^i{}_\mu$.

The vectors $e_i$ have a "symmetry" in the following sense. If $\Lambda_j{}^i$ is a Lorentz transformation, then the new set of vectors $\Lambda_i{}^je_j$ is a tetrad:
$$g(\Lambda_i{}^ke_k,\Lambda_j{}^le_l)=\Lambda_i{}^k\Lambda_j{}^lg(e_k,e_l)=\Lambda_i{}^k\Lambda_j{}^l\eta_{kl}=\eta_{ij}$$